# Strange animation glitch while UISearchController is presenting search results controller

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

UISearchController's search bar is assigned to table view header. Strange animation glitch is present. When search bar becomes first responder it suddenly jumps up for some pixels and then animation goes fine. While animating back after pressing Cancel same glitch is present at the end of animation.

[animation glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7epKm.gif)

Source code: https://github.com/Jeka53/SearchBarAsTableViewHeader

Any suggestions???

Comment: Can you share you code. Because this is very little to go on.

Comment: sure, https://github.com/Jeka53/SearchBarAsTableViewHeader

Comment: @RakeshaShastri any idea?